# Coordinate geometry and Trignometry.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Find the condition so that the line $px +qy=r$ intersects the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ in points whose eccentric angles differ by $\frac{\pi}4$.

Though I know how to solve it using parametric coordinates, I was wondering if there's an another approach which is less time consuming.

Comment: Not sure what eccentric angles are in this context, unless you mean angles with the lines through the focus, but have you tried expressing the ellipse in polar coordinates?

Comment: The parametric approach doesn't seem so time-consuming to me. Could you show your work? Or explain what you found so hard.

Comment: @Prime Mover Eccentric angle for a given point (x,y) on the ellipse = value of $t$ such that $x=a\cos t,y=b \sin t$. This terminology comes from astronomy.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P_1 = (a \cos t , b \sin t) $ and $P_2  = (a \cos(t + \phi), b \sin (t + \phi))$ where $\phi = \dfrac{\pi}{4} $, then we need to satisfy two conditions:

1. $P_1$ is on the line $ p x + q y = r $, therefore,

$$ p a \cos t + q b \sin t = r \hspace{20pt}(1) $$

2. $P_2$ is on the line as well, hence,

$$ p a \cos(t + \phi)  +  q b \sin(t + \phi)  = r \hspace{20pt} (2) $$

This last equation becomes

$$ \cos t ( p a \cos \phi + q b \sin \phi ) + \sin t ( - p a \sin \phi + q b \cos \phi ) = r \hspace{20pt} (3)$$

And after substituting $ \cos \phi = \sin \phi = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $, it becomes,

$$ \cos t ( p a + q b ) + \sin t ( q b - p a ) = \sqrt{2} r \hspace{20pt} (4)$$

Now solving $(1)$ and $(4)$ for $\cos t$ and $\sin t $, we find that

$ \cos t = -r \dfrac{ (q b - p a) - \sqrt{2} q b }{  p^2 a^2 + q^2 b^2 } $

$\sin t = -r \dfrac{  \sqrt{2} p a - (p a + q  b) }{   p^2 a^2 + q^2 b^2 }$

Since $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1$, then the condition is

$ \dfrac{ ( p^2 a^2 + q^2 b^2 )^2 }{ r^2 } = (q b - p a)^2 + (pa + q b)^2 + 2 ( q^2 b^2 + p^2 a^2 ) - 2 \sqrt{2} ( q b (q b - p a) + p a ( pa + q b) ) $

Simplifying the right hand side,

$ \dfrac{ ( p^2 a^2 + q^2 b^2 )^2 }{ r^2 } = 4 (p^2 a^2 + q^2 b^2) - 2 \sqrt{2} ( q^2 b^2 + p^2 a^2 ) $

Dividing through by $(p^2 a^2 + q^2 b^2)$, yields,

$ \dfrac{p^2 a^2 + q^2 b^2}{r^2} = 4 - 2 \sqrt{2} $

And this is the condition on the line.